# make report in access

Tags: sql, t-sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

In MS Access I have 3 tables:

**tblUser**(UserID,Age(teen,adult,old),Company,...)
to store users information

**tblCourse**(CourseID,...)
to store course information

**tblInformation**(CourseID,UserID,...)
to store which user takes which cCourse

I need to make a report that shows me how many (teen,adult,old) users each company has, and that company take which course, and how many users in each company take each course.

Example report how I would want it to look, made in Excel
+ tables with some data:

[image]

Comment: Hi Sahar.  Welcome.  Could you please provide DataTypes for the tables.  Also would it be possible for you to include a small sample of the data for us to look at.  We could help you a lot more with just a bit more information.  I've included a link to a Microsoft paper on the topic.  You might try working through those examples and seeing if you have specific questions.

Comment: Normally, it's expected from you to show what you have tried so far to solve you problem.

Comment: @Android777 dear it's how i want.that link is a picture

Comment: I have cleanud up the question and inserted the picture, but I did not understand the middle part of your report description, so that I did not edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the data in your tables in the screenshot, I created this query:

```
SELECT tblUsers.Company, tblCourses.CourseName, tblUsers.Age
FROM (tblInformation LEFT JOIN tblCourses ON tblInformation.CourceCode = tblCourses.Course) LEFT JOIN tblUsers ON tblInformation.UserID = tblUsers.UserID;
```

Which resulted in this data:

[image]

I then put this data into a spreadsheet formatted as a table (you can either export it to spreadsheet and then format the data as a table or link your spreadsheet to this query in Access; linking is better in my opinion because you can just refresh the spreadsheet for new data from Access):

[image]

Highlighting the above table in Excel, I inserted a pivot table, and set up the fields in this configuration:

[image]

...which creates this pivot table:

[image]

Is this what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

Please see my comment above, but this link might prove useful in your investigation.

[Create a Simple Report](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-simple-report-408e92a8-11a4-418d-a378-7f1d99c25304)